# Why am i getting an error while exporting html page to word?

Tags: php, html, export

i got an error while trying to add new row of the table, everything is normal and i can export my html page to ms word.

im getting error like this

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\exportword2.php:216) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\exportword2.php on line 217

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\exportword2.php:216) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\exportword2.php on line 218

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\exportword2.php:216) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\exportword2.php on line 219

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\exportword2.php:216) in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\exportword2.php on line 220
```

here is my code

```
        <tr>
            <td>13. </td>
            <td>Upah Pekerja</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>Minimum</td>
            <td colspan="4">Rp. 100000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>Maximum</td>
            <td colspan="4">Rp. 100000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Upah Pekerja Harian</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>Minimum</td>
            <td colspan="4">Rp. 100000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>Maximum</td>
            <td colspan="4">Rp. 100000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>14.</td>
            <td>Sistem Hubungan Kerja</td>
            <td colspan="6">:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>a. Untuk Waktu Tertentu</td>
            <td colspan="6">: 3 Orang</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>b. Untuk Waktu Tidak Tertentu</td>
            <td colspan="6">: 3 Orang</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <?php
            header("Content-Type: application/vnd.msword");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=hasilekspor.doc");
    ?>

</body>
```

i already done exporting until i add new row of table, i got an error above

error occure when i add new row after this row

```
<tr>
    <td>13. </td>
    <td>Upah Pekerja</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td>Minimum</td>
    <td colspan="4">Rp. 100000</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc the correct Extension MIME Type
.doc      application/msword you can have a look at the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by
> normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very
> common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or
> another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are
> output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a
> single PHP/HTML file.

```
<?php
// header must be before any sent output 
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.msword");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=hasilekspor.doc");
 ?>
<html>
...
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was helpful